# Datagridview CheckboxColumn Shaded or (X) Mark when unchecked

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Good Morning

I have a column in `DataGridView` that generates checkbox and in relation to that I have also a lot of columns in my table that is called `2016,2017 and so on` and all of that is `TinyInt`

Now here is the image for both of them:

[image: Table]

[image: Datagridview]

Now here is my question, instead of uncheck how can make it shaded or X mark in the `DataGridView` Column?

here is my code in populating the `DataGridView`:

```
Dim sql1 As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("Select * from period_closure", con1)
Dim ds1 As DataSet = New DataSet
Dim adapter1 As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter
con1.Open()
adapter1.SelectCommand = sql1
adapter1.Fill(ds1, "MyTable")
DataGridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables(0)
con1.Close()
ds1.Tables(0).Columns(2).DataType = GetType(Boolean)
Me.DataGridView1.Columns(0).Frozen = True
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
    DataGridView1.Columns.Item(i).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic
Next
DataGridView1.Columns("PeriodID").Visible = False
DataGridView1.Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
```

Comment: Make it an image column or create your own cell or draw it yourself, you have a few options.

Comment: by the way sir creating own cell or image column would not be fitted because i have also a code that when i update check or ucneck the column it will update my table also. how about the drawing? can you shed me some knowledge with that?

Comment: @Zaggler How about making the cell color red when it is uchecked?

Answer (score 0):

First of all download 'X' image in google, or create your own.

then try to add this in your code.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.Paint
 If CheckBox1.Checked = False Then
        Try
            Dim newImage As Image = Image.FromFile("E:\Projects\Library\BER-X.jpg")
            Dim x As Single = 0
            Dim y As Single = 0
            Dim width As Single = CheckBox1.Width 'You can also try this CheckBox1.Width - 3
            Dim height As Single = CheckBox1.Height 'You can also try this CheckBox1.Height - 3
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, x, y, width, height)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

the `X` mark in the checkbox is not accurate in the position but you can fix it by your self. Try it and Explore it to fit it in your system. :)

Hope this will help you.